# POST https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/ipfs/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false 403 (Forbidden). HTTPError: ipfs method not supported

Tags: reactjs, api, blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

Below is how i create the client.

```
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client';
```

```
const projectId = 'xx';
const projectSecret = 'xx';
const auth = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${projectId}:${projectSecret}`).toString('base64')}`;
const options = {
  host: 'ipfs.infura.io',
  protocol: 'https',
  port: 5001,
  apiPath: '/ipfs/api/v0',
  headers: {
    authorization: auth,
  },
};
const dedicatedEndPoint = 'https://xx.infura-ipfs.io';
const client = ipfsHttpClient(options);
```

Here is the function that will be called from front-end that takes in a file, uploads to IPFS and returns URL. Please note that the "ipfsHTTPClient()" is just the create function.

```
const uploadToIPFS = async (file) => {
    try {
      const added = await client.add({ content: file });

      const url = `${dedicatedEndPoint}${added.path}`;

      return url;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file to IPFS: ', error);
    }
  };
```

The error I am getting is

```
POST https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/ipfs/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false 403 (Forbidden)
```

When i console log the error it says the IPFS method is not supported.

On the IPFS forum, i have seen someone say that add function does not work anymore but i have also seen people using it and it working. Im not sure whats wrong here.

Here is how i call the function on front-end

```
const { uploadToIPFS } = useContext(NFTContext);

// function called from useDropzone
const onDrop = useCallback(async (acceptedFile) => {

    const url = await uploadToIPFS(acceptedFile[0]);

    setFileUrl(url);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above code is correct and the error was from Next.js

Needed to add

```
images: {
    domains: ['xx.infura-ipfs.io'],
 },
```

to the next.config.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem
so make sure first you have installed buffer

```
npm install --save buffer
```

then import it in your file

```
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
```

then it works successfully

```
import { create } from "ipfs-http-client";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

const projectId = "YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID";
const projectSecret = "YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_SECRET";
const auth = `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${projectId}:${projectSecret}`).toString(
  "base64"
)}`;

const client = create({
  host: "ipfs.infura.io",
  port: 5001,
  protocol: "https",
  apiPath: "/api/v0",
  headers: {
    authorization: auth,
  },
});

const uploadFiles = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUploading(true);
    if (text !== "") {
      try {
        const added = await client.add(text);

        setDescriptionUrl(added.path);
      } catch (error) {
        toast.warn("error to uploading text");
      }
    }
```